# How do I use emotes to communicate with my team on Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one, overwatch

Everyone I play with is always saying *"Hello!"* Or *"Group up!"* constantly, I feel horrible just standing there not being able to respond, to show that I heard them and are listening to them.

How can I respond back to them? I'm playing on the Xbox One if that matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dragonrage is pretty spot on there. To bring the communication window up press <kbd>↓</kbd> on the D-pad and while holding that down, use the Right Thumbstick to scroll in the direction of the option that you want to activate (in your case, <kbd>↖</kbd> for "Thank" and <kbd>↘</kbd> for "Group Up")

[image]
<sup>Image from: Reddit /r/Overwatch</sup>

To activate the action, release the <kbd>↓</kbd> on the D-pad while staying hovered over the option with the thumbstick.

I have occasionally found the timing of releasing the D-pad will just cause the menu to disappear and nothing to be activated, so make sure that you are still pointing in the correct direction with the Thumbstick when you release the D-pad.

[Source](http://twinfinite.net/2016/05/overwatch-how-to-do-emotes/)

Answer (score 1):

To do this for Xbox (PlayStation is the same I think) push "down" on the d-pad to bring up the communication wheel, and then highlight the option that says emote. For pc, press "c" to open the communication wheel.

[Source](http://twinfinite.net/2016/05/overwatch-how-to-do-emotes/)